# Mocha expects method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js

So my situation is: 
I have a 2 modules that have the same structure like that:

```
module Module1
  class Config

    def fee_rate
      2
    end
  end
end
```

So, say, Module2 would have class Config with the method fee_rate, just with a different value (those are actually implemented in a rails engine, but it shouldn't matter)

and then my model can use either Module1 or Module2 to get the fee rate value like that:

```
def config
  @config ||= "#{module_name.titleize}::Config".constantize.new
  @config
end

def get_value
  config.get_fee * some_other_value
end
```

What I'm trying to test is if get_fee function was called on the correct class:

```
"#{model.module_name.titleize}::Config".constantize.any_instance.expects(:get_fee).at_least_once
model.get_value
```

and on the line when I call get_value I get the following error -  undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass. I'm completely lost now, so I'd appreciate any help and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting up an expectation for `get_fee` you are preventing the actual method call from happening. Because you haven't set a return value for the expectation, e.g. `expects(:get_fee).at_least_once.returns(3)` it is returning nil, hence the error message.

You may have more success by doing away with the expectation altogether and checking that the right type of config class is created, e.g.

```
model.get_value
assert_equal "#{model.module_name.titleize}::Config".constantize, 
             model.config.class
```

Comment: I'll probably go with `returns()`, cuz now I understand how expects works. Thanks!